# Use of session in role based access control (RBAC)

Tags: rbac

I am trying to understand access control based on RBAC model. I referred to the following link.

[NIST RBAC Data Model](http://www.mind-it.info/2010/01/09/nist-rbac-data-model/)

I haven't understood this part clearly as mentioned in the excerpt -

*"Each session is a mapping of one user to possibly many roles, i.e., a user establishes a session during which the user activates some subset of roles that he or she is assigned. Each session is associated with a single user and each user is associated with one or more sessions. The function session_roles gives us the roles activated by the session and the function user_sessions gives us the set of sessions that are associated with a user. The permissions available to the user are the permissions assigned to the roles that are activated across all the user.s sessions."*

**Question** - How can session be used to activate roles ? The relationship between the user / group and roles are inserted as admin data. So, how does session activate subset of roles for a user ?

P.S -> I asked this question earlier [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/592353/Security/sessions-RBAC) but without an answer. May be this question is too basic to ask but I am keen to understand it. Any use case or a link will definitely be helpful.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In RBAC, administrators give permissions by assigning them to roles, and in addition by assigning roles to users. As you know, for a user to be able to use a particular permission, he will have to have been assigned at least one role that provides said solution.

So each user has a set of roles assigned to him. During a session, he can choose to activate (or deactivate) any of these roles, but no other. The activated roles determine which permissions are available to the user at a given time during the session. This is useful, for example, for dynamic separation of duty constraints, where two roles A and B can be assigned to the same user U, but can't be used together. Therefore, if U wants to use A, he will have to deactivate B before activating A.

Comment: Thanks Eraser, How does a user choose to activate / deactivate roles ? And when does he do that? Considering a simple web application where a user has to be authenticated via login form, does the user choose the roles after submitting the login form ? If yes, how does it happen ? If not, after a successful login, when a session is created, how are roles activated / deactivated to this user?

Comment: It depends on the authorization framework you're using, and how you implement access control in your application. For example, in a web application, visiting a particular page may trigger the activation/deactivation of some roles.
The RBAC standard doesn't make activation and deactivation of roles during a session mandatory, and some frameworks will simply activate all roles at login. In that case, of course, dynamic separation of duty constraints are useless. You may want to have a look at the [RBAC standard](http://csrc.nist.gov/rbac/sandhu-ferraiolo-kuhn-00.pdf).

Comment: Thanks Eraser, I think, I've begun to understand it. From an an excerpt, Ref Flat RBAC, Page 5 from the link above -  "In other cases, user is given choice to activate and deactivate roles in a given session at the user's discretion".  Where is this kind of web application used ? Seems to me that its the admin web application that you've mentioned in your answer.

Comment: Indeed, in general the end user will not directly see the activation/deactivation of roles, as it will be handled behind the scenes by the application.

Comment: Why not just have another account with the associated Role? This seems more duty-separating.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience in implementing RBAC, I pretty much avoided using dynamic management of multi-sessions.

At first it sounded like a pretty neat and flexible idea, but as you questioned on who activates/deactivates roles (and when), I realized the complexity and security risks wasn't worth the effort (my personal opinion).

The important thing to understand here and for which @Imontriux (above) mentioned:

> "This is useful, for example, for dynamic separation of duty
>   constraints, where two roles A and B can be assigned to the same user
>   U, but can't be used together. Therefore, if U wants to use A, he will
>   have to deactivate B before activating A."

Most of the time, there are separation of duty constraints that must apply and in order to honour this, I simply chose to only have/manage one valid session per user at a time.  If a user wants to authenticate under different set of roles, he/she is responsible in logging out and logging back in.

It pretty much simplified a lot of my code.  It was a compromise I chose and could easily live with.

Comment: Selecting and activating at authentication time still is dynamic management. The standard doesn't say it has to happen "of the fly". As to security, it doesn't prevent bad things from happening, but it provides an excellent audit trail, one that proves the person knowningly commited fraude (for example). We have government applications where a civil servant is in charge of paying out subsidies, but can also login as a citizen and apply for a subsidy. This can not be technically avoided, and it also something you don't want to avoid.

Comment: @WanWizard Yes, I understand your point.  What I envision though are systems like Windows where you are a regular user and when you try to execute a privileged command, it pops up for your credentials to escalate your privileges.  Obviously, Windows probably doesn't swap in/out one session with another but rather provides additional permissions.  But that is what I understand in 'dynamic'.  If Windows would require you to completely log out and then log back in with the privileged user, to me that is different (ie: static) and not really dynamic management.

Comment: I understand that from a user friendliness point of view, you would want something like this. However, I think from a security point of view, the Windows design is fundamentally flawed. It uses the credentials of another user to elevate your rights, which from an audit point of view is a nightmare. And I my case there is no other user, it's the same user having multiple roles, and because of segregation of duty, the user may not have the permissions associated to these roles at the same time.